# Can't Install Ubuntu Inspiron 14R-5420

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, uefi

I'm new to ubuntu and I'm having a big problem installing/using it.  I want to partition my hard drive and I've tried this with a USB, DVD but I can't.
I created a bootable USB and I'm not able to boot it from my computer. Normally you put the usb in the port, restart the computer, enter boot options and that's it. I can't do it. Whenever I restart my computer There's no F2 option to enter the setup, just F12 option to enter Boot Manager and whenever I enter that I get this.

[image]

I've tried getting into legacy and I still can't do it.
I did this with a DVD but still nothing.
What can I do?

Edit: I downloaded ubuntu 14.04.3 64 bit

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you try?

Comment: I downloaded 14.04.3

Comment: Is it 64 or 32 bit?

Comment: 64, sorry I didn't specify that earlier.

Comment: You probably just need to create the USB drive with a different tool. Older ones, and even some new ones, do not create drives that are bootable in EFI mode, which is what you need. [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) is a Windows tool that can do it. Your best bet is to use the option to create a GPT disk for UEFI booting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a manual for this laptop. It should tell you how to get into UEFI aka bios settings. It is not always <kbd>F2</kbd>. It may be <kbd>ESC</kbd> or some other key combination. For Dells <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> may work.

Some laptops have a fast or quick boot option. In this mode the laptop does not detect USB sticks on boot. You will need to disable this feature.

Also you can try to fully power off your laptop, not just reboot. In this case that boot from USB may work.

But you need also to take in account that Windows 8 does not really power off the computer by default, it just hibernates it. This Windows feature should be disabled prioir to Ubuntu installation.

Comment: I didn't know about the hibernation. I'll check that and answer as fast as possible

Comment: Try Fn+F1 too key.

Comment: I was able to enter

Comment: https://scontent-lax3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtf1/v/t34.0-12/12021919_10153470421205862_1486909366_n.jpg?oh=312725de198ef3ff0b124eb5177a63cb&oe=56015A44  now what should I do to get that option of fast boot disabled

Comment: Try to add boot option with inserted Ubuntu installer stick.

Comment: It worked! Im installing it right now. Thanks.